# file_get_contents failed to open stream with a valid url

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm trying to use this code in a php file.
I want get the source code from this url and parse the content.

```
<?php 
  $fuente = file_get_contents('http://www.akiracomics.com');
  echo $fuente;
?>
```

The problem is, after execute the code I received this error

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.akiracomics.com) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Connection timed out in XXXXXX/test.php on line 2

I tried from the same server to other url and works perfect.

Any idea?

Thanx

Comment: Maybe they are blocking scrapers such as yourself

Comment: Works fine at my end, blocking issue it might be

Comment: Works here too, from a PHP CLI script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. I need to use a curl_exec instead file_get_contents.
With this code, everything works fine.

```
            $curlIMG = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curlIMG, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.es");
            curl_setopt($curlIMG, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curlIMG, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            $imgBinary = curl_exec($curlIMG);
            curl_close($curlIMG);
```

Comment: what if I do it with both and it still don't work ? Worst file_get_contents don't works on Symfony Framework project, but works with a single file script

Answer (score 0):

It's working here, probably you're making too many requests (what are you trying to do, by the way?) and they are blocking incoming requests from your server.

Comment: I'm doing a database with the comicbook publish, and everyday I check this page to found new content.
I talked with the owners and they said me that, no problem with this.
I will contant with them to know if they are blocking me.

Thanx